# database columns and foreign key normalization

Tags: database, standards, normalization

i am building a new system (lamp - ubuntu server, php 5.3, mysql 5.5, apache 2, redis) for my company (like a version 2.0)

i want to make it right and make it better.

i want to use innodb and i want to know if there's a standard in naming columns and foreign keys.

for example:

```
table_a
 table_a_id
 table_a_name
 etc...
```

this way when you left join its very easy to distinguish but if you have long name it can be painful to write sql.

```
table_a
 id
 name
 etc...
```

this way, the table is very easy to understand but you have to use the alias or table name every time you left join.

is naming a database.table.column part of the database normalization?

Comment: totally a personal question, as long you keep a standard and you stick with it's all good

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the naming convention of database, tables, columns, keys, foreign keys has nothing to do with the database normalization.

although, i recommend to keep the same naming convention structure everywhere. all my names are pretty standard, single word or if it's a phrase it's separated by underscore, no numbers nor special chars. same for columns, keys and fk (with exception with number) and i always use plurials (its rare you only have 1 db, 1 table with 1 column and 1 row)

here's what i do:

```
databases: companies
tables: clients, clients_products, products
column: id, name, address, city
key: name
unique key: name
```

this way when you query your data, it's very clear what you request or what you look for.

Answer (score 0):

> is naming a database.table.column part of the database normalization?

No. Loosely speaking, normalization has to do with increasing data integrity by restructuring tables based on identifying certain kinds of dependencies among attributes.

**The names of tables and columns are your API.**

ISO 11179, *Information Technology—Metadata Registries (MDR)*, is an international standard for representing *metadata* in a *registry*. Although it's aimed at semantics, not tables and columns, a lot of database designers use it as a guide to naming tables and columns. In large organizations, it's really valuable.  (Functional dependency, which *is* part of normalization, is a semantic thing.)

You might find it useful to explore the difference between a table name and an object class. (*Object class* in this sense has nothing to do with object-oriented programming. It's a technical term in ISO 11179.)

[A review copy of part 5 (PDF)](http://metadata-standards.org/Document-library/Documents-by-number/WG2-N1551-N1600/WG2N1580_WD_11179-5_Ed3.pdf), *Naming and Identification Principles*, is available online. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_11179) might be a more enduring reference. (Might not.)